# Examples for spectrum of an operator

Tags: spectral-theory

Looking for easy-to-understand examples for the spectrum of an operator, preferably so that they exposed some special properties. The right shift is a nice example of an operator which does not have a point spectrum. What is the  simple most example of an operator which has all three spectra? Etc
Cross-linking to other questions or websites is highly recommended.

Comment: Example 1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205477/spectrum-of-this-operator